# Node.js async looping function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js and am struggling to know if this is the correct way to do the following:

I am using [lupus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lupus) to handle the for loop, and I am querying the twitter API, I am then trying to get the largest id in the returned json, for this I am using [lodash](https://lodash.com). Once I have this value I want to then run the loop again but this time with the value passed into the function. I loop through returned JSON with [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
lupus(0, loopLength, function(n) {

        var maxId;

        T.get('favorites/list', {count: 200, max_id: maxId}, function(err, data, response) {
          if (err) {
            throw (err);
          }

          maxId = _.max(_.pluck(data, "id"));

          async.each(data, function(file, callback) {
            console.log(file)
          }, function(err){
            if( err ) {
              console.log('A file failed to process: '+ err);
          });
        })


      }, function() {
        console.log('All done!');
      });
})
```

It seems `maxId` never gets set so the `.each` loop never gets the next set of JSON. My question is am I doing this correctly, and how do I get the value of maxId from the `.each` function.

Comment: Your code will not be successfully parsed as it is.

Comment: @thefourtheye I missed some brackets when copying and pasting, updated now.

Comment: You don't need to use `async.each` to synchronously loop over the `data`? In fact it doesn't even work as you never call the "next" callback.

Comment: What is  `looplength`?

Comment: @Bergi Just a variable set for the length of the loop

Comment: @Bergi why don't I need to use ```async.each```? Sorry for daft question just new to node.

Comment: But why do you loop at all? You're not using `n` anywhere, so why repeat the body (and how often)? You do not need `async.each` because `console.log` is not asynchronous. Just use `_.each`.

Comment: Because I am saving them to a db, I just haven't copied this code in. Ok I have used ```._each``` thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two asynchronous things going on (the lupus "loop" and the `T.get` calls) and essentially no coordination between them.

Because the `T.get` will be asynchronous, I wouldn't use lupus (ugh!) here at all:

```
var index = 0;
var maxId;
next();
function next() {

  T.get('favorites/list', {count: 200, max_id: maxId}, function(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      throw (err);
    }

    maxId = _.max(_.pluck(data, "id"));

    async.each(data, function(file, callback) {
      console.log(file)
    }, function(err){
      if( err ) {
        console.log('A file failed to process: '+ err);
    });

    if (++index < loopLength) {
      next();
    } else {
      console.log('All done!');
    }
  });
}
```

---

There are a couple of unrelated things in the code that don't look right:

1. You're using `maxId` when you've never assigned a value to it, in the first call to `T.get`. Seems like you want some kind of initial value there.
2. You're throwing an error out of the `T.get` callback. Does the documentation for `T.get` tell you it will do something useful with that error? If not, you probably want to do something else. Throwing there won't, for instance, stop the loop in your original code (it **will** with the code above).